# Xcode 7: "Unknown type name 'size_t'"

Tags: c, xcode, clang, c-preprocessor, osx-elcapitan

(The other questions that StackOverflow may have my answer don't appear to help my particular problem.)

My clients' marketing people want my product to support Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan).  This seems to be a reasonable request; however it's giving me some trouble.

I'm actually using Xcode *7.3.1*; if I understand correctly that was the last version that supported El Capitan.

I also had some trouble with building on Sierra and High Sierra so I'm building *on* El Capitan *for* El Capitan.

The troublesome code is in C; it's a prototype in [CCAN's list's](https://ccodearchive.net/info/list.html) `<ccan/list/str.h>`:

```
size_t strcount(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
```

At first, the compiler couldn't find `<stddef.h>` so I added an absolute path for the system headers.  Now a particular source file - that works just fine on later Xcode releases - give me "Unknown type name 'size_t'"

I added `<stddef.h>` to that C file but it didn't help.  The platform-dependent include file was not searched because the following two preprocessor symbols weren't defined.  Just because All Is Fair In Love, War And Debugging I defined them:

```
// Todo: This is an awful hack
//       I'm trying this because Xcode 7.3.1 seems to think that size_t is undefined.
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__

#include <stddef.h>         // MDC El Capitan branch
```

This got the same Unknown type complaint.

At this point, I figured I should ask for help.  Have you any insights for me?

Comment: `size_t` is defined in `<stddef.h>` as you already know. But it's buried in two levels of conditionals, and there's an `#undef` in the mix. So my next step would be to add some conditionals with `#warning` into the code to see what's defined.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have the command line tools for XCode 7.3.1 installed.  Consider running `xcode-select install` to get them installed.  That should avoid the need for the absolute path change, and might fix the other problems too.  Otherwise, we need more code – an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You may need to think about using `clang -v` (or `gcc -v`) to see what is being run to compile your code.  You may need to look at the `-mmacosx-version=10.11` option and/or the `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` environment variable.